# Powershell: Change date to int?

Tags: powershell

I have a cmdlet that is expecting an `int32` for the date instead of a normalized input.

`Set-CTXGroupPolicyConfiguration`, `RebootScheduleStartDate` wants `int32`-input. For instance, if i enter this into policy manually, it has tomorrow, `1/18/2015` as `132055314`.  Coming up blank with what that number is even referring to.

Comment: First thing to do is figure out what it's incrementing. What do you get if you put in 1/19/2015?

Comment: increments by 1 for each day added. 1/19/2015 was 132055315.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was fun. I found this [Citrix Support](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX130232) site where they describe how the dates are stored as a dword (uint32) value in registry. The dword-value is created like:

1. Date is split into year, month and date
2. Each value is converted to hex-value
3. The hex-values are combined (16bit year, 8bit month, 8bit day) in the pattern `yyyyMMdd`
4. The combined hex-value is converted to decimal

I've created a couple of functions to convert the dates for you:

```
function ConvertFrom-DwordDate([int32]$DwordValue) {
    #Ex. $DwordValue = 132055314
    #Convert to hex with 8 chars (16bit year + 8bit month + 8bit day)
    $hex = $DwordValue.ToString('X8')
    #Ex. $hex = 0x07df0112 = 0x07df(year) 0x01 (month) 0x12 (day)

    #Convert to date string
    $datestring = '{0:D4}\{1:D2}\{2:D2}' -f [convert]::ToUInt32($hex.Substring(0,4),16), [convert]::ToUInt32($hex.Substring(4,2),16), [convert]::ToUInt32($hex.Substring(6,2),16)
    #Convert to datetime and output
    $datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($datestring,'yyyy\\MM\\dd',$null)
    #Output
    $datetime
}

function ConvertTo-DwordDate([datetime]$Date) {
    #Convert to combined hex
    $combinedhex = '{0:X}{1:X2}{2:X2}' -f $Date.Year, $Date.Month, $Date.Day
    #Convert to decimal
    $decimal = [convert]::ToUInt32($combinedhex,16)
    #Ouput
    $decimal
} 

ConvertTo-DwordDate -Date (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
132055314

ConvertFrom-DwordDate -DwordValue 132055314

søndag 18. januar 2015 00.00.00
```

Comment: Impressive Frode F.!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a ridiculously old post but it's the top response on Google for "powershell get-date as int".

```
$DateInt = [Int]((Get-Date).addDays(-100).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))
```

Comment: Is the addDays necessary?

Comment: For what we were doing yes and it's the reason we were hunting for how to do it. You can get the dword value from the registry and convert hex to int but you can't do the math on the int after the fact if you cross the month boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the previous answers are so complicated. Why not just:

```
$nTicksPerDay = 1e7 * 60 * 60 * 24
$nDate = [int](((get-date).ticks) / $nTicksPerDay)
```

On Aug. 1, 2023, that gives $nDate = 738,732.
Since

```
2,023 * 365 + 7 * 30 = 738,605
```

I presume that with adjustments for leap years and the actual number of days before Aug. 1, $nDate is the correct number of days since Jan. 1, 0001.